# gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I followed this [document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) and I’m hitting this error. Could you let me know what I’m missing? I tried several things the whole day and nothing has worked? Please let me know if you know any solution on this?

```
$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Sun 2019-12-15 05:15:27 UTC; 17s ago
   Listen: /home/xx/myproject/myapp/myapp.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

Dec 15 05:15:27 ubuntu-s-01 systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.


$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-12-15 04:22:54 UTC; 53min ago
 Main PID: 15788 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]:     self.stop()
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]:   File "/home/xx/myproject/xxenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbi
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]:     time.sleep(0.1)
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]:   File "/home/xx/myproject/xxkenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbi
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]:     self.reap_workers()
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]:   File "/home/xx/myproject/xxenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbi
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 gunicorn[15788]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 15 04:22:54 ubuntu-s-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```